# Cipher decoding

Tags: string, encryption

Ok, so as part of a challenge I've been trying to work out a cipher for the following string... `r33z://sB.83swq.myw/5s/tzEx9tkzGSI/wy5sozy23o1.tzq?5=EpBGoFnm`

It's pretty clearly a "fairly" simple character shift of +10 from the original, which turns `r33z` into `http` and `wy5sozy23o1.tzq` into `movieposter.jpg`. What I can't work out is the REST of the character set, and where it wraps. I tried doing all caps alphabet then all lowercase alphabet then numbers, shift 10 so the key would look like...

> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890
>   KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890ABCDEFGHIJ

But this turns up a pretty strange URL aside from the obvious correct spots, that doesn't link to anything. Any thoughts?

And as a note, so I don't get given a hard time about it. The challenge says I can use "all the tools at my disposal," and I consider stackoverflow a very valuable tool ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I don't consider myself a tool however.

Comment: The font for this forum isn't one of the ones where each character takes up the same amount of space (forget the technical term,) so the key won't line up quite right unless you change the font.

Comment: @Arvandor Mono-spaced is the term you were looking for.

Comment: You can learn how to format your question by clicking the "help" (question mark) link when you're posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
echo 'r33z://sB.83swq.myw/5s/tzEx9tkzGSI/wy5sozy23o1.tzq?5=EpBGoFnm' |\
    tr 'A-Za-z0-9' '0-9A-Za-z'
```

Comment: Aha, that did indeed work! That's a pretty slick trick, and does make sense for the shift being 10 characters. The annoying part though? My manual decode was correct except for ONE character being lowercase instead of a capital. Derp! Thanks Adam